# Why doesn't a TLS certificate with a domain name mask that doesn't match the site name trigger a warning in the browser?

Tags: tls, certificates, web-browser

I visited `stackoverflow.com` and found in Chrome that its certificate is valid and has `Common Name (CN)   *.stackexchange.com`. After that I checked a fingerprint for `stackexchange.com` and it matched the first one. I thought that Chrome would show me a warning that the domain didn't match, as `stackoverflow.com` doesn't redirect to `stackexchange.com` and it doesn't have a CNAME to it - `dig +short stackoverflow.com cname` - shows nothing. My question is: how does Chrome recognise that `stackoverflow.com`  is part of `*.stackexchange.com`?

Comment: The Keyword you are looking for is "Subject Alternative Name"

Comment: Indeed, just found out that in Firefox, Chrome doesn't show SAN, it confused me. Thanks!

Comment: Actually it does, in Details. But it should be more prominently displayed for sure.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A certificate Common Name is not the only thing used to validate a certificate. It is actually only used for very primitive certificates that lack a subjectAltName extension.

The StackOverflow certificate has got a [subjectAltName](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.6) field with the following dNSNames in it, which allow the certificate to validate for StackOverflow.

```
*.askubuntu.com
*.blogoverflow.com
*.mathoverflow.net
*.meta.stackexchange.com
*.meta.stackoverflow.com
*.serverfault.com
*.sstatic.net
*.stackexchange.com
*.stackoverflow.com
*.stackoverflow.email
*.stackoverflowteams.com
*.superuser.com
askubuntu.com
blogoverflow.com
mathoverflow.net
openid.stackauth.com
serverfault.com
sstatic.net
stackapps.com
stackauth.com
stackexchange.com
stackoverflow.blog
stackoverflow.com
stackoverflow.email
stackoverflowteams.com
stacksnippets.net
superuser.com
```

Comment: The Common Name field isn't used to validate certificates any more at least in Chrome (but I imagine also in most other browsers as well) for several years. SubjectAltNames is required these days.

Comment: Yeah in the case of TLS it's completely unused, but CN is still used in  some others x.509 use cases

Answer (score 30):

Originally certificates were only valid for a single name. But with the growth of the web, it was very common that the same server would be accessible under multiple names. So certificates were extended to permit multiple names. The use of the Common Name (CN) field has been [deprecated since 2000](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2818#section-3.1) in favor of the subjectAltName field (Subject Alternative Name, often abbreviated SAN). The subjectAltName field can contain a list of names (or name patterns starting with a wildcard), not just a single name.

The subjectAltName field for the certificate offered by `https://stackoverflow.com/` includes `stackoverflow.com` as well as `*.stackexchange.com`, `*.stackoverflow.com`, `*.meta.stackexchange.com`, etc. Chrome recognizes `stackoverflow.com` in the subjectAltName field. It's a bit weird that it only shows the CN value in the overview, but you can view the certificate details and see the SAN entries under “*.stackexchange.com” → “Certificate” → “Extensions” → “Certificate Subject Alternative Name”.