# Host header is preferred by OpenSSL over SNI

Tags: tls, certificates, openssl, web

As I understand a webserver shall serve SNI first and ignore `HOST` header from HTTP 1.1 as TLS handshakes occurs before HTTPS, to test I came up with this example: two domain names under the same IP address `stackexchange.com` and `stackoverflow.com`:

```
(echo GET / HTTP/1.1
echo Host: stackoverflow.com 
echo Connection: close
echo) | openssl s_client -quiet -servername stackoverflow.com -connect 151.101.1.69:443 \
| grep URL
```

Returns `<p>URL: stackoverflow.com/</p>` - I expected this.

```
(echo GET / HTTP/1.1
echo Host: stackexchange.com 
echo Connection: close
echo) | openssl s_client -quiet -servername stackexchange.com -connect 151.101.1.69:443 \
| grep URL
```

Returns  `<p>URL: stackexchange.com/</p>` - Expected.

```
(echo GET / HTTP/1.1
echo Host: stackexchange.com 
echo Connection: close
echo) | openssl s_client -quiet -servername stackoverflow.com -connect 151.101.1.69:443 \
| grep URL
```

Returns `<p>URL: stackexchange.com/</p>` - I expected to see `stackoverflow.com` instead, my question - why I did not get it?

Comment: WTF, stackexchange.com blocks requests that have no User-Agent header? (see `curl --user-agent '' https://stackoverflow.com/`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some confusion here : there are two layers that interact relatively little, the TLS session establishment, and the HTTP request. The SNI option of TLS session initiation permits the server to choose the right certificate to present to the client, in case it uses more than one certificate. In the case of the StackExchange sites, they seem to have one frontend mutualized between all sites, using subjectAltNames for every site, so the SNI option doesn't change anything. The TLS session establishment does not take into account the `Host:` header of the HTTP request at all, so OpenSSL doesn't prefer the header, because for OpenSSL the header is data and passed to the application layer untouched and unseen.

Once your TLS connection is established, normal HTTP behavior applies and the `Host:` header is used.

In many cases, one could establish connection with one hostname in the SNI extension, and another in the `Host:` header, and for all purpose the `Host:` header will take precedence. As @dave_thompson_085 mentioned, doing that on purpose is called domain fronting and it can actually be used to evade some form of censorship (when one entity forcibly close connections if the domain observed in the SNI extension is blacklisted).

Comment: Stack's certificate's SAN is detailed in [this other Q](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/264919/why-a-tls-certificate-with-a-domain-name-mask-that-doesnt-match-site-pattern-do) from the same OP. Using different Host than SNI is or has been used to avoid censorship in some countries (which can see SNI and block based on it, but not Host) and is called 'domain fronting'.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 for example - server has two websites with individual tls certificates and I send a SNI record to use server1 and HOST header with server2, HOST header shall reroute a request and I will get a reply from server2, is it correct?

Comment: @GhostRider: that's up to the server. SNI and Host are both supposed to represent the 'desired' server, so if they're different a server isn't _required_ to accept it, but in practice (often? usually?) the TLS and HTTP parts of the software are separate and each doesn't care about the other. However if what you're talking to is actually a firewall, load balancer, CDN, or similar, they may well route based on SNI and the subsequent HTTP request with different Host won't work.